# Extract substring from a string in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring

Is there any way to extract substring from a string like below

My real string is   "NS09A"   or "AB455A"  but **i want only   "NS09" or "AB455" (upto the end of numeric part of original string).**

How can i extract this?

I saw google search answers like using position of starting and endinf part of substring we can extract that ,But here any combination of "Alphabets+number+alphabets"  .I need only  " "Alphabets+number"

Comment: is string always "alpha", "numeric", "alpha"?

Comment: no  ,some cases it will be like that  ,in normal case its like "alpha"+ "numeric"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this code:

```
   NSString *originalString = @"NS09A";

    // Intermediate
    NSString *numberString;
    NSString *numberString1;


    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
    NSCharacterSet *numbers = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];


    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&numberString];

    [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:numbers intoString:&numberString1];

    NSString *result=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",numberString,numberString1];

    NSLog(@"Finally ==%@",result);
```

Hope it Help You

**OUTPUT**

```
Finally ==NS09
```

**UPDATE:**

```
NSString *originalString = @"kirtimali@gmail.com";

NSString *result;
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:originalString];
NSCharacterSet *cs1 = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"@"];

[scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:cs1 intoString:&result];

NSLog(@"Finally ==%@",result);

output:
Finally ==kirtimali
```

Comment: @Kirti Mali How to substring when comes to Mail validation. I like to get substring upto `@`. `Ex: mailname@gmail.com` means then i want only `mailname`. Can you edit your post with this solution?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps not everybody will agree, but I like *regular expressions*. They allow to specify
precisely what you are looking for:

```
NSString *string = @"AB455A";

// One or more "word characters", followed by one or more "digits":
NSString *pattern = @"\\w+\\d+";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                       options:0
                                     error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string
                        options:NSMatchingAnchored
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
if (match != nil) {
    NSString *extracted = [string substringWithRange:[match range]];
    NSLog(@"%@", extracted);
    // Output: AB455
} else {
    // Input string is not of the expected form.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try This:-

```
NSString *str=@"ASRF12353FYTEW";
NSString *resultStr;
for(int i=0;i<[str length];i++){
    NSString *character = [str substringFromIndex: [str length] - i];
    if([character intValue]){
        resultStr=[str substringToIndex:[str length]-i+1];
        break;
    }
}
NSLog(@"RESUKT STRING %@",resultStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSScanner` and the `scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:` method to specify which characters should be used to stop the parsing. This could be in a loop with some logic or it could be applied in conjunction with `setScanLocation:` if you already have a method of finding the start of each section you want to extract.

---

When using `scanUpToCharactersFromSet:intoString:` you are looking for the next invalid character. It doesn't need to be a 'special' character (in a unicode sense), just a known set of characters that aren't valid for the content you want. So, you might use:

```
[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"1234567890"] invertedSet]
```

Comment: can i mention that am stopping with a number instead of special character

Answer (score -3):

You can use `- (NSString *)substringWithRange:(NSRange)aRange` method on `NSString` class to get a substring extracted. Use `NSMakeRange` to create the `NSRange` object.

Comment: Why a down vote? It answers the questions to extract the substring.

Comment: I think, the votedown was made, bcoz your answer tells to extract the substring with the use of a range. In this question, there is no particular range. There is need to first find the range, then perform trimming operations, upto it.

Comment: @PankajRathor i dont know why u got down votes,but for the effort to write a answer here  i 'll add one up vote now.

Comment: @Navi You're not supposed to upvote answers for the sake of it being an answer. You upvote if you think it's a good answer.